# recv always return EAGAIN but tcpdump shows 0 packets dropped by kernel

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, tcpdump

I'm trying to read udp packets using `recv` non-blocking mode in a loop as shown below, however the call always return `EAGAIN`, but tcpdump shows that `0 packets dropped by kernel`, what could be the cause of `EAGAIN`?

```cpp
  for (;;)
  {
    const auto rc = ::recv(fd, data, maxSize, MSG_TRUNC);

    if (rc < 0)
    {
      switch (errno)
      {
        case (EINTR):
          break;

        case (EAGAIN):
          spdlog::error("EAGAIN");

        ...
      }
    }
    else if (rc == 0)
    {
      throw std::runtime_error("Connection closed");
    }
  }
```

tcpdump ctrl C return:

```
668 packets captured
981 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Comment: What's the matter with the `0 packets dropped by kernel`? It simply means that the kernel did not drop any packet on its own. It's pretty normal to get an `EAGAIN` on a **non-blocking** socket, it just means that there are no packets in the queue at the time of your `recv`. Are you saying that your application is missing packets?

Comment: Also, note that you should check for both `EAGAIN` and `EWOULDBLOCK`, they have the same meaning in this case, but can have different values. POSIX allows returning any of the two errors.

Comment: You are using non-blocking mode why? Using it in a spin loop like this is pointless. The right way would be with `select()`, but in a loop like this it is also pointless. Use blocking mode. And '0 packets dropped by kernel' is irrelevant. That isn't proof that any datagrams arrived for your socket.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I though the reason why there are no packets in the queue was because the packets were dropped by the kernel, if this is not the reason, what could cause `recv` always return `EAGAIN`? Or why there were no datagrams arriving at the socket @user207421?

Comment: `if (rc == 0) ... "Connection closed"` -  There is no such thing as a connection close with UDP sockets since there is no connection start and connection end and not even a real connection. Returning 0 here just means a datagram of size 0 was received, which is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

*0 packets dropped by kernel* just means that the *packet capture mechanism* in the kernel did not drop any packets. It has nothing to do with the receiving socket.

Note also that tcpdump captures packets before they are processed by the firewall, so it might well be that they get blocked by the firewall and never received on the socket even if tcpdump can capture these.

Also, calling `recv` in a busy loop will likely return `EAGAIN` most of the time since most of the time no data are available on the socket. Non-blocking sockets are usually used together with something which detects socket activity and blocks if there is no activity, i.e. `select`, `poll`, `kqueue`, ... . Combining these mechanisms allows to deal with many sockets in a single thread. Using a busy loop on a single socket instead almost never makes sense.

Comment: The firewall was turned off. The `recv` call just always returned `EAGAIN` when I both started the receiver and sender at the same time, looks like the packets never arrived at the socket, what could be the reason?

Comment: @betteroutthanin: the reasons could be a) packets are blocked by firewall b) you are trying to reach the wrong sockets, i.e. the socket is bound to a different ip,port than what was sent to c) you are misinterpreting what you see d) the code you show does not reflect what you are actually running, so no statements can be made. Unfortunately the code fragment you are showing is not sufficient to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I thought the return of `EAGAIN` was because the socket is non-blocking, it turn out that it was caused by setting the timeout with `SO_RCVTIMEO`. It's actually blocking socket, double checked the potential causes you listed above, still can't figure out why it just can't receive any data from the socket. Also `nc -l` doesn't respond either.

Answer (score 0):

It's all because of docker host network doesn't work with OSX, so my application running insider the container cannot receive the UDP packets sending from the host.